# what is the difference between the meaning of the following questions?

Tags: questions

I am not sure if the following questions are right. If that is the case I would like to know:

- What is the difference between them?
- When it is better to use one or the other?

The first question is this:

> What I am supposed to do?

The second question is this:

> What do I supposed to do?

I appreciate any explanation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically incorrect.

> I am supposed to [wash the dishes].

Is an expression which means that people expect you to do something.

Since it is a sentence with **be**, you would have to ask the question by inverting the verb and the subject:

> What **am I** supposed to do?

A similar meaning would be conveyed with the modal verb *should*, and the syntax would be:

> What **should** I do?
>   
> You **should** wash the dishes.

A good way to determine question syntax is to look at the answer you expect, and **reverse-engineer** to get the question.

You can find a lot of resources on how to ask questions in English on the Internet. For example: http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/questions1/menu.php